# Imported contacts are empty

Tags: iphone, ms-office, contacts, gmail, import

I have an odd problem. I got an iphone5 and of course, I want all my contacts from my nokia into my iphone, I imported the contacts into outlook, then exported to an csv file, then imported to gmail and it worked perfectly until that point. When I imported the gmail contacts to my iphone, all the names were there, but barely any mobile numbers. However, in my gmail profile everythings seems to be ok, so I doubt that there is a field organisation problem.
If anyone has an idea, please help me, that thing is driving me crazy!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong. It seems the phone number types were the problem. They were classified as "Other". I changed them all to "Mobile" and it worked.

I hope this helps somebody, because I looked the problem up for hours and didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing through Outlook and Gmail to transfer nokia contacts to your iphone - i'd simply use the Nokia Desktop Sync sofware to export the nokia contacts to your pc then import the contact files from the PC to the iPhone using an app to [import contacts to iPhone](http://www.copytrans.net/copytranscontacts.php).